# MYSQL : Between or equal

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why its not working if my both value are same I already use with equal operator. User need to select date from & to, if the user select both same date of from & to which is `2017-08-13` it should still display all the dates of `2017-08-13` and unfortunately not working.

```
SELECT * FROM master_data.speed_of_service where 
( trans_time >= '2017-08-13' and 
trans_time <= '2017-08-13')
```

It only work if there are interval between dates

Comment: can you share the table schema?

Comment: Does the column also store the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess, it is because `trans_time` has a time component.  One easy fix is to extract the date:

```
SELECT ss.*
FROM master_data.speed_of_service ss
WHERE date(trans_time) >= '2017-08-13' and date(trans_time) <= '2017-08-13';
```

A better solution would be to add one day to the "to" date:

```
SELECT ss.*
FROM master_data.speed_of_service ss
WHERE trans_time >= '2017-08-13' AND
      trans_time < '2017-08-13' + interval 1 day;
```

This is better because it still allows the use of an index.